# If there are no duplicates in 2 tables which you want to combine, would you use UNION or UNION ALL

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

As UNION ALL is faster than UNION, would you use UNION ALL to combine 2 tables which dont have any duplicates ? Why/Why not ?

Answer (score 1):

You should always default to `UNION ALL` when you want to combine tables.  `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates -- and in almost every database, you get the overhead even when there are no duplicates.

You should only use `UNION` when you specifically want to incur that overhead because you really do want to remove duplicates.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the response.

Comment: I'd be recommending beginners to use `UNION` unless they really understand the schema and can be sure there will _never_ be duplicates. (And beginners are poor at understanding that.) Unexpected duplicates cause all sorts of subtle errors, especially in aggregates (`SUM, COUNT, etc`).